# CMake Undefined symbols using external library poco

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, poco, clion

When building a project using the poco library, I get the following errors:

```
    /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/alan/Library/Caches/clion11/cmake/generated/12b7e3f2/12b7e3f2/Debug --target csvreader -- -j 2
    [ 50%] Linking CXX executable csvreader
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "Poco::AtomicCounter::AtomicCounter(int)", referenced from:
          Poco::ReferenceCounter::ReferenceCounter() in dataConn.cpp.o
      "Poco::AtomicCounter::~AtomicCounter()", referenced from:
          Poco::ReferenceCounter::~ReferenceCounter() in dataConn.cpp.o
      ... [many more]
```

This uses the following CMake build file:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
    project(csvreader)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    set(SOURCE_FILES dataConn.cpp )
    #set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    #set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

    set(POCO_ROOT "/Users/alan/ClionProjects/csvreader/poco-1.6.1-all")
    set(POCO_INCLUDE_DIR "${POCO_ROOT}/Foundation/include" "${POCO_ROOT}/Util/include" "${POCO_ROOT}/Data/include" "${POCO_ROOT}/Data/SQLite/include")
    set(POCO_LIBRARY_DIR ${POCO_ROOT}/lib/Darwin/x86_64)
    message(STATUS "[ ${POCO_ROOT} ]" " POCO_ROOT")

    include_directories("${POCO_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    set(POCO_LIBS "")
    set(POCO_LIB_NAMES PocoFoundationd PocoUtild libPocoDatad PocoDataSQLited )
    message(STATUS "[ ${POCO_LIB_NAMES} ]" " POCO_LIB_NAMES")
    #FIND_LIBRARY(POCO_LIBS
    #        NAMES ${POCO_LIB_NAMES}
    #        PATHS ${POCO_LIBRARY_DIR}
    #        NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    #message(STATUS "[ ${POCO_LIBS} ]" " POCO_LIBS")
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${POCO_LIBRARY_DIR})
    add_executable(csvreader ${SOURCE_FILES} )
    target_link_libraries(csvreader  ${POCO_LIBRARY_DIR} ${POCO_LIBS})
```

I checked the static libraries attempting to be accessed, and the first symbol not found, is in the library. So this seems to be a problem that CMake cannot find the libraries themselves.
Should it be relevant, this is on OS X 10.10.5 and everything is built 64 bit.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

In response to Robin's comment below, I tried un-commenting FIND_LIBRARY and inserting the first library (which contains the symbol Poco::AtomicCounter::AtomicCounter(int) ). See below. Trying to build with this resulted in the same errors, with the above symbol and the others not found.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
    project(csvreader)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    set(SOURCE_FILES dataConn.cpp )
    #set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    #set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

    set(POCO_ROOT "/Users/alan/ClionProjects/csvreader/poco-1.6.1-all")
    set(POCO_INCLUDE_DIR "${POCO_ROOT}/Foundation/include" "${POCO_ROOT}/Util/include" "${POCO_ROOT}/Data/include" "${POCO_ROOT}/Data/SQLite/include")
    set(POCO_LIBRARY_DIR ${POCO_ROOT}/lib/Darwin/x86_64)
    message(STATUS "[ ${POCO_ROOT} ]" " POCO_ROOT")

    include_directories("${POCO_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    set(POCO_LIBS "")
    set(POCO_LIB_NAMES PocoFoundationd PocoUtild libPocoDatad PocoDataSQLited )
    set(POCO_LIB_1 PocoFoundationd)
    message(STATUS "[ ${POCO_LIB_NAMES} ]" " POCO_LIB_NAMES")
    FIND_LIBRARY(POCO_LIBS
            NAMES ${POCO_LIB_1}
            PATHS ${POCO_LIBRARY_DIR}
            NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    message(STATUS "[ ${POCO_LIBS} ]" " POCO_LIBS")
    #LINK_DIRECTORIES(${POCO_LIBRARY_DIR})
    add_executable(csvreader ${SOURCE_FILES} )
    target_link_libraries(csvreader  ${POCO_LIBRARY_DIR} ${POCO_LIBS})
```

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the `FIND_LIBRARY` command? At the moment, you are passing a directory and an empty string to `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: I had tried that first, using FIND_LIBRARY, but it gave the same error.

Comment: One `FIND_LIBRARY` command only finds one library. If you want to search for all four libraries set in `POCO_LIB_NAMES`, you’ll need four different `FIND_LIBRARY` commands.

Comment: Please double-check if you have debug version of libraries. Default release library names are without 'd' suffix (e.g. from HomeBrew). If not, just try change PocoFoundationd to PocoFoundation etc.